# Is this a bug with AutoMapper's PascalCase naming convention regex?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm attempting to leverage AutoMapper in order to not have to manually write a lot of code mappings. This appears to be working fine for everything other than this one class:

```cs
CreateMap<AccountConnection, AccountConnectionDto>();
CreateMap<Account, AccountDto>();
CreateMap<Address, AddressDto>() // <--- this one
  .ForMember(dest => dest.StreetAddress1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.street_address_1))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.StreetAddress2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.street_address_2))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.StreetAddress3, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.street_address_3));
```

If I don't manually map those 3 members, then when I run `config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` it throws.

```
Exception Details: AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException:
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
=================================================
Address -> AddressDto (Destination member list)
Proj.Data.Address -> Proj.API.AddressDto (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
StreetAddress1
StreetAddress2
StreetAddress3
```

I am using the following naming conventions in my profile:

```cs
SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
```

These are the only properties with numbers in the property name so I dug in to the AutoMapper source on GitHub and found the Regex for the PascalCaseNamingConvention that I'm using in my project. It is:

`(\p{Lu}+(?=$|\p{Lu}[\p{Ll}0-9])|\p{Lu}?[\p{Ll}0-9]+)`
If I throw that in https://regex101.com and then test it against my property name `ShippingAddress1` I get two matches, `Shipping` and `Address1`.

Ruh-roh! My source property name is `shipping_address_1` (Don't ask) so that isn't going to work. Is this because my naming convention is broken, or should the PascalCaseNamingConvention match `shipping_address_x` to `ShippingAddressX`? (Went to raise an issue on the AutoMapper github but they ask newcomers to post on SO first, to see if people think it is a legitimate bug or not).

Answer (score 0):

From my testing detailed below, I believe the naming conventions specified are the wrong way around:

```
public class Address
{
    public string StreetAddress1 { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDto
{
    public string street_address_1 { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Prints nothing
    PerformMappingTest(new PascalCaseNamingConvention(), new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention());
    // Prints "Test"
    PerformMappingTest(new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention(), new PascalCaseNamingConvention());

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void PerformMappingTest(INamingConvention source, INamingConvention destination)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = source;
        cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = destination;
        cfg.CreateMap<Address, AddressDto>();
    });
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    var address = new Address { StreetAddress1 = "Test" };
    var addressDto = mapper.Map<Address, AddressDto>(address);
    Console.WriteLine(addressDto.street_address_1);
}
```